# Data Coverage Plot using matplotlib and Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, pyqtgraph

I have created data Coverage of time series which is in pandas Data Frame and would like to plot the data coverage in Matplotlib or PyQtGraph.

**DATA FRAME**

```
DateTime    WD98    WS120   WS125B  WD123   WS125A
31-07-2013  100 99.9    99.9    NaN NaN
31-08-2013  100 100 100 NaN NaN
30-09-2013  100 100 100 NaN NaN
31-10-2013  100 100 100 NaN NaN
30-11-2013  100 100 100 100 100
31-12-2013  100 100 100 100 100
31-01-2014  100 100 100 100 100
28-02-2014  100 100 100 100 100
31-03-2014  100 100 100 100 100
30-04-2014  100 100 100 100 100
31-05-2014  67.1    100 100 67.1    7.7
30-06-2014  NaN NaN 100 0   69.2
31-07-2014  NaN NaN 100 0   100
31-08-2014  NaN NaN 100 0   96.2
```

I would like to plot in below fashion (Broken bar Chart)

[image: Data Coverage Done in Excel Conditional Formatting]

The above plot was done using Excel Conditional Formatting. Please help me.

```
DataCoverage >= 90 (Green)
DataCoverage >= 75 and DataCoverage < 90 (Yellow)
DataCoverage < 75 (red)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [seaborn.heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

```
import seaborn as sns

df = df.set_index(df.pop('DateTime').dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
g = sns.heatmap(df, cmap=['r','y','g'], annot=True, fmt='.0f')
g.set_yticklabels(g.get_yticklabels(), rotation=0, fontsize=8)
```

Result:

[image]

**UPDATE:** corrected version:

```
x = df.set_index(df['DateTime'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')).drop('DateTime', 1)    
z = pd.cut(x.stack(), bins=[-np.inf, 75, 90, np.inf], labels=[1.,2.,3.]).unstack().apply(pd.to_numeric)    
g = sns.heatmap(z, cmap=['r','y','g'], fmt='.0f', cbar=False)    
g.set_yticklabels(g.get_yticklabels(), rotation = 0, fontsize = 8)
```

Result:

[image]